# Show popup before page finishes loading

Tags: jquery

In my page I have the following jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#element_to_pop_up').bPopup({
        loadUrl: 'test.php',
    }); 
});
```

When I load the page this popup displays fine.

Within my page I have a form that submits some data and then streams the results page. When I submit the form the popup doesn't get displayed until the form has finished processing.

I'm assuming this is because the forum reloads the original page and the jquery isn't being processed until the page has finished loading.

Any way around that ?

Thanks

Comment: How do you submit the form? Using php or javascript? Post the whole code please.

Comment: `I'm assuming this is because the forum reloads the original page and the jquery isn't being processed until the page has finished loading.` yes you are right here..

Comment: @Tom , you mean to say you want the popup as soon as you submit the form and also it must stay there untill the page the completed realoading??

Comment: @Tom looks like you need to make use of ajax, Else I don't see any way this is going to work.

Comment: @RajshekarReddy - thanks for the reply - when the form is submitted the page loads, the form is processed and then the popup appears.. I want it to appear before the form is processed.

Comment: I'm using standard html to submit the form.

Comment: @Tom when you say `form is processed` do you mean server side process